# Does selenium not work with & in url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am crawling urls

https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind

The above works fine but on the same page with more than one link i.e.:

https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind&feed=shared

it gives an empty result. It is the same for:

https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind&feed=shared&gen0=male
https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind&feed=shared&gen0=female .

```
def getVideoTrend(self):
    binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind&feed=shared")
    assert "YouTube Trends" in driver.title
    video_trend = []
    for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('video-item'):
        print s
        video = {}
        videourl = s.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
        video['url'] = videourl
        videotitle = s.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('alt')
        video['title'] = videotitle
        video_trend.append(video)
    print video_trend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you are not waiting for the elements to be loaded in the DOM.

Try do something like this :

Import selenium webdriverwait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Wait for the elements to load before you get them.

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('video-item'))                                   
for s in elements:
    print s.text
    video = {}
    videourl = s.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    video['url'] = videourl
    videotitle = s.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('alt')
    video['title'] = videotitle
    video_trend.append(video)
print video_trend
```

This code works for me

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

class Test(object):
    url1 = "https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind"
    url2 = "https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind&feed=shared"
    url3 = "https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind&feed=shared&gen0=male"

def get_video_trend(url):
    driver.get(url)
    assert "YouTube Trends" in driver.title
    video_trend = []
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('video-item'))                                   
    for s in element:
        print (s.text)
        video = {}
        videourl = s.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
        video['url'] = videourl
        videotitle = s.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('alt')
        video['title'] = videotitle
        video_trend.append(video)
    print (video_trend)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_video_trend(Test.url1)
    get_video_trend(Test.url2)
    get_video_trend(Test.url3)
```